# How to push the user to another page without breaking a long running request?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

My stack is **Vuejs UI, Python Flask/Nodejs Express** Backends.

I am implementing an application that performs a long running task with a request to the backend,
While this task is running the user only sees a loading page.

My question is if i put a button in the loading page that the user can click to be redirected/pushed to another page to keep using the system, How can i still have the running request and not to break it?.

Comment: if the request is not made in a component that is being dismounted when change page, then the request should not be break, I think.

Comment: Probably easiest to call a Vuex action.  But what does the request do and how have you tested it?  Even destroying a component won't stop a `fetch` or `setTimeout`, `axios` call, etc.